# Proof of a polynomial matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations, characteristic-polynomial

Consider a $2 \times 2$ matrix

$$ A= \left[\begin{array}{c} 2 & 7\\ 1 & 8\end{array}\right] $$

For this matrix, or for any $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$, why does $A^2 - \mbox{tr}(A) \cdot A + \det(A) I = 0$?

---

**Some of my findings:**

While looking for an answer in google, I found that the characteristic equation of a $2 \times 2$ matrix is almost similar to the equation I've given above. The characteristic equation is $$\lambda^2 - \mbox{tr}(A) \cdot \lambda + \det(A) I=0$$ where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of the matrix $A$. Being curious I computed the eigenvalue of the above matrix $A$ and found that $\lambda=9,1$ and surprisingly also $\det(A) = 9$ and if I replaced $A$ (which is a matrix) of this equation $A^2 - \mbox{tr}(A) \cdot A + \det(A) I = 0$ by determinant of the matrix $A$ then also the equation satisfies  $|A|^2 - \mbox{tr}(A) \cdot \det(A) + \det(A) I=0$ and I understand the reason of this is $|A|=\lambda$.

But I cannot comprehend why $A^2 - \mbox{tr}(A) \cdot A + \det(A) I=0$ is true in general where $A$ is a matrix and $\lambda$ is a constant number and also why this is only true for $2 \times 2$ matrix and is there any relationship between this equation and characteristic equation?

***PS:*** I am not much familiar with linear algebra, so much humble request is to you to keep your explanation within "matrix and determinants" domain as much as possible.

Comment: Well! seems if you are interested to learn linear algebra then you can go for 
#1[$3b1b$YouTube: Linear Algebra](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0-GT3co4r2y2YErbmuJw2L5tW4Ew2O5B), #2[MIT OpenCourseware by Gilbert Strang](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL49CF3715CB9EF31D) 
Coming to your question I remember I book **Engineering Mathematics** by *H K Dass* that could really help you understand what exactly you are looking for more important is the proof for the above theorem also you can refer **Engineering Mathematics** by *Ravish Singh & Mukul Bhatt*  **Don't miss 3b1B**

Comment: @DarshanP. I would but I don't have enough time to do this anytime soon. Right now I am preparing for an engineering entrance exam (similar to JEE Advance in your country) and I don't have Linear Algebra in my syllabus, so it practically would be a waste of time to study it now. But I found that formula while solving a matrix problem but couldn't prove it anyway (I know it can be proven by setting up a generic $2 \times 2$ matrix but the calculation would be complicated).

Comment: Wish I could have upvoted your honest comment though the community responses are for the benefit of everyone so if it's not you who'll read then someone else for sure that's why one has to add sources/thread that people may find useful. Also, [All the best+of luck for your exam!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzS9k.png)

Answer (score 3):

This is a special case of the general [Hamilton-Cayley theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem): if
$$
p_A(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n=\det(A-xI)
$$
is the characteristic polynomial of the (square) matrix $A$, then
$$
a_0I+a_1A+\dots+a_nA^n=0
$$
(the zero matrix).

In the case of a $2\times2$ matrix the characteristic polynomial is
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix} a_{11}-x & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}-x \end{bmatrix}
=x^2-(a_{11}+a_{22})x+(a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21})
=x^2-\operatorname{Tr}(A)x+\det(A)
$$
There is no need to prove the general theorem: for a $2\times 2$ matrix, just plug in and look what happens.

For instance, the entry at positiion $(1,1)$ of $A^2$ is
$$
a_{11}^2+a_{12}a_{21}
$$
and so in $A^2-\operatorname{Tr}(A)A+\det(A)I$ we get
$$
a_{11}^2+a_{12}a_{21}-(a_{11}+a_{22})a_{11}+a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}=0
$$
as you can easily verify. Similarly for the other entries.

Comment: Why Hamilton-Cayley instead of Cayley-Hamilton?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Oh, it's named both ways. I believe that the first to state it was Cayley, but the first to prove it rigorously was Hamilton.

Comment: @egreg, wikipedia says $\det(xI-A)$ instead of $\det(A-xI)$. Why?

Comment: @NazmulHasanShipon That merely switches the sign when $n$ is odd. The roots are preserved.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo It's essentially equivalent, up to multiplication by $(-1)^n$. The form I prefer is better when dealing with factorization, but it's just personal preference.